# Problema con HTTP - NodeJS & Typescript

Tags: nodejs, typescript, http

Estoy construyendo una pequeña API con el módulo **HTTP** de **Node** más **Typescript**. El problema es que cuando guardo los cambios y hago la primer request con **GET** u otro verbo, el servidor se cae. Si envío otra petición, ahí recién funciona. Ya he trabajado con **HTTP** antes, pero empecé a migrar a **Typescript** y me pasó esto.

El código de pruebas es el siguiente:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req: any, res: any): any => {
        const { url, method }: { url: string, method: string } = req;
        if(url === '/' && method === 'GET') {
            return res.end(JSON.stringify({ code: 200, notification: 'OK' });
        };

        res.end(JSON.stringify({ code: 200, notification: 'error' }));
}).listen(4000);
```

A la primera ocurre esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al segundo intento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté hacerlo con **promesas** pero sigue funcionando mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el código que has pasado te falta cerrar un paréntesis, dentro del return del `if`, no se si se deba a ello, he ejecutado tu código y no me sale el problema que mencionas, he usado Postman y `curl` pero no hay error en la primera petición.

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req: any, res: any): any => {
        const { url, method }: { url: string, method: string } = req;
        if(url === '/' && method === 'GET') {
            return res.end(JSON.stringify({ code: 200, notification: 'OK' }));
        };

        res.end(JSON.stringify({ code: 200, notification: 'error' }));
}).listen(4000);
```

Comment: No era puntualmente eso, porque lo escribí rápido para el ejemplo en este post. Es el API Client Insomnia el problema. No me había acordado de usar curl u otras herramientas! Gracias

Comment: Ojo, ahora con curl + watch -n1 estoy viendo en tiempo real que al guardar un cambio en cualquier fichero del proyecto, la conexión se cierra y luego vuelve a conectarse